# Access violation error when using glCreateBuffers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, nvidia

I am trying to run [OpenGL Red book examples](https://github.com/openglredbook/examples). I am able to compile the projects in MS VS 2017. However, when I execute some of the examples it throws me the following exception.

> Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in Project_1_1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation executing location 0x00000000. occurred

This occurs for the line:

```
glCreateBuffers( NumBuffers, Buffers );
```

I have come to understand from reading the forums that `glCreateBuffers` works if the GPU supports OpenGL 4.5. I tried using `glGenBuffers` and indeed it works.

I ran `glewinfo` and it shows me that GL_VERSION_4_5 and GL_ARB_direct_state_access are missing. So it appears that my GPU doesn't support OpenGL 4.5.

However, I have Nvidia GTX 1050 with updated drivers, and according to documentation it ought to support OpenGL 4.5. The system information in Steam shows 4.5 OpenGL support. The codes work fine when I compile in Linux. I am required to use OpenGL 4.5.

Relevant details:

1. Windows 10
2. Dell XPS 15 with i7 7700 HQ
3. Nvidia GTX 1050
4. Visual Studio 2017

I am compiling codes on Windows for the first time so it is possible that I am missing something obvious. The codes work on Ubuntu 16.04.

**Edit (Added code)**
The relevant section of the code is from the [this repository](https://github.com/openglredbook/examples/tree/master/src/01-triangles):

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Triangles.cpp
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "vgl.h"
#include "LoadShaders.h"

enum VAO_IDs { Triangles, NumVAOs };
enum Buffer_IDs { ArrayBuffer, NumBuffers };
enum Attrib_IDs { vPosition = 0 };

GLuint  VAOs[NumVAOs];
GLuint  Buffers[NumBuffers];

const GLuint  NumVertices = 6;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// init
//

void
init( void )
{
    glGenVertexArrays( NumVAOs, VAOs );
    glBindVertexArray( VAOs[Triangles] );

    GLfloat  vertices[NumVertices][2] = {
        { -0.90f, -0.90f }, {  0.85f, -0.90f }, { -0.90f,  0.85f },  // Triangle 1
        {  0.90f, -0.85f }, {  0.90f,  0.90f }, { -0.85f,  0.90f }   // Triangle 2
    };

    glCreateBuffers( NumBuffers, Buffers );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer] );
    glBufferStorage( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, 0);

    ShaderInfo  shaders[] =
    {
        { GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "media/shaders/triangles/triangles.vert" },
        { GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "media/shaders/triangles/triangles.frag" },
        { GL_NONE, NULL }
    };

    GLuint program = LoadShaders( shaders );
    glUseProgram( program );

    glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT,
                           GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// display
//

void
display( void )
{
    static const float black[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black);

    glBindVertexArray( VAOs[Triangles] );
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// main
//

#ifdef _WIN32
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
  _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
#else
int
main( int argc, char** argv )
#endif
{
    glfwInit();

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Triangles", NULL, NULL);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    int api, major, minor, revision, profile;

    api = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CLIENT_API);
    major = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR);
    minor = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR);
    revision = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_REVISION);
    profile = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE);

    gl3wInit();

    init();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        display();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Comment: The code compiles fine. When I start the debugger, it throws the said exception at line glCreateBuffers( NumBuffers, Buffers );

Comment: Please show all the relevant code in the question itself. Do you create a valid OpenGL 4.5 context? Are you loading the extensions since windows supports only OpenGL 1.1 natively? Are you even running your code on the NVidia card?

Comment: I have added the relevant code. I am not sure what you mean by adding OpenGL 4.5 context. I don't think I have done any of that. How do I run the code on the NVidia card? I will search a bit about these two points.

Comment: The OpenGL has to be set when you create the window. The exact way depends on the windowing library used (which is not visible from the posted code). NVidia card: Since you have a Nvidia card and an integrated intel card, you have to make sure that your application starts at the correct one. There should be a setting somewhere in the nvidia control panel.

Comment: Your still missing the code where you declare `Buffer`, `NumBuffers`, ArrayBuffer.

Comment: @Surt I have added more codes.

Comment: @BDL The windowing library is GLFW. I set preferred Graphics processor to my GPU instead of "auto-select". That resolved the issue. Thank you. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things that should be checked if you are sure that your graphiccard supports OpenGL 4.5:

- Make sure that your application actually requests a OpenGL 4.5 context (For example, by setting the correct `glfwWindowHint` for that)
- Make sure that the application uses the correct card. This is especially an issue on Notebooks with both, a dedicated GPU (AMD or NVidia) and an integrated one from Intel. The setting for this should be somewhere in the Nvidia control panel or in the AMD equivalent.